# Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/core/Response

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to run a jersey client and facing this issue.
This problem gets out when i try to run the class on command prompt. While if i run it on intellij it works fine. Can anybody help me with that? Ps: i'm a beginner in java

Comment: is that class a core class or your own class ?

Comment: @niceman what do u mean with core class? ps: im sorry but im a beginner in java :/

Comment: Looks like a typo to me. It should be `javax` instead of `javx`.

Comment: IntelliJ appears to be smart enough to add this JAR to your CLASSPATH when you run in the IDE.  You need to learn how to set CLASSPATH when you run on the command line.

Comment: @sinclair oh it's javax actually. my mistake, sorry

Comment: @duffymo u'r saying i have to add a new path on environment variables path? or im not getting it right ?

Comment: Not environment variables; -cp command line argument to java.exe when you run.  You have to know how CLASSPATH works or you can't write Java.

Comment: oh i know what u mean. thnx

Answer (score 1):

@Anja.M we need more details in order to be able to help you. The most important thing when it comes to a java application is to create the class path correctly. I believe this is stated above. You need describe all this dependensies into the java command when you are starting the application.  Jersey depends on libraries as well the class that is throwing your exception is contained within **javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar**. This file contains the missing  **javax/ws/rs/core/Response** This file you need to include in the class path the following way:

java -classpath classpath1;classpath2...

Let me summarize. You have two type of dependencies one type is inside the  /api folder when you download the jersey bundle.  The second one is located under -lib

You need to make sure that /api content and the lib is in your class path. Maybe not all jar files are needed for the client side , but you can find out later. As a start include them all.

Comment: I think Maven is too much for this user.

Comment: And @duffymo i may not be very good as you or others in java, coz i have less than a year using it, but i think it's important to ask and learn the things u dont know...

Comment: @Anja  I edited the post. Check please if this is working.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov thank u again. It worked but it gives another error now :/ Exception in thread main com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException. I used the following command : java -cp .;"../../../lib/*" package.Class